# How to iterate through an array of objects and replace one object while in the loop of chckebox : checked each function - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In jquery in a button click i am looping through all the rows which have their checkbox ticked / checked , at the same time i have to create an array of objects of the selected or modified one .

Cant reset the Array as , if one `Company` came in the first time and didnt come in the second time as that row was not checked , i have to retain the previous values

check out this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/y7jqb5hp/1/

so suppose you select two rows at first and add some text in text box then the array of objects will be having two objects with that property but second time he selects one row out of that two rows and deselect other one and give some other value text box , we have to update the object with that company name with that value

**HTML**

```
 <table>
      <tr>
      <th>checkbox</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
        <td>Alfreds </td>
        <td>Maria </td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
        <td>Centro </td>
        <td>Francisco </td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
        <td>Ernst </td>
        <td>Roland </td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
        <td>Island </td>
        <td>Helen </td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
        <td>Laughing  </td>
        <td>Yoshi </td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
        <td>Magazzini </td>
        <td>Giovanni </td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="button" onclick="getdetails()" value="click me"/><br>
     <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="name"><br>
```

**jquery**

```
var selectedRows=[];

function getdetails() {
var modifier = $('#txtBox').val();
        $.each($("input[name='eachRow']:checked").parents("tr"), function () {


        selectedRows.push ({
          company : $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
          contact: modifier


        })

        console.log(selectedRows);

        });


        }
```

**css**

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Just reset the array before the loop

Comment: can not reset it as if some ID came and 2nd time they dont checkbox that same ID , i have to retain the previous values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code would do the trick.

```
var selectedRowsArray= [];


$.each($("input[name='eachCheckbox']:checked").parents("tr"), function () {


ID= $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(); 
var found = selectedRowsArray.filter(function (el) {
    return el.ID === ID;
});
if (found.length === 0) {
    selectedRowsArray.push({                   
        ID: ID,
        Col2value : $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
        Col3value : //somevalue manupulated,
        Col4value : //somevalue manupulated
    });
} else {
    // Do the updating here with the object `found`
}

});
```

Link to the solution https://jsfiddle.net/y7jqb5hp/3/

Comment: if its first time , selectedRowsArray - ID property is defined error coming up

Comment: there is another problem , first time its not pushing as found is false .

Comment: so first time it will push the values , when second time it comes it will check the IDs , if its find something update that obejct , if that ID is new it will add that object

Comment: It should push in the first time. Do you have a fiddle for it? It will be easier to debug it in a fiddle.

Comment: sorry my bad , its pushing first time , but second time its creating another object for the found ID . where it should update the existing object in array.

Comment: So your requirement is first time you add in the array and second time update the value in array?

Comment: added fiddle for you

Comment: can you help me to update the selectedrow array object with object in found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143368/discussion-between-tripathy-and-harshit-jain).

Comment: I have updated the code in https://jsfiddle.net/y7jqb5hp/3/ . Please take a look. I have also tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function to get the object with the ID in the array **selectedRowsArray**

Try this

```
var objs = selectedRowsArray.filter(function(row){return row.ID == ID;});
```

`objs` returned is an array of objects having id as ID in your array.

Now you can iterate through the `objs` and upadate the properties of the object.